# If $\int_V f \;dV = 0$ when can we say that $f=0$ everywhere

Tags: calculus, integration

If $\int\limits_V f \; \mathrm dV = 0$ can we say that $f=0$ everywhere? Or what conditions are there on concluding this.

In particular I want to solve the PDE $\nabla^2 f=f^3$ on the region $$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}|x^2+y^2<1\}$$ with $f=0$ on the boundary.

Comment: Seb note that $f$ could change sign ! But if in addition you have that $f$ is positive then you right

Comment: If this holds for only one given domain $V$, no chance unless you add the condition that $f\geqslant0$ everywhere. If this holds for every subdomain $V$, you win. In both cases the conclusion is that $f=0$ except on a set of measure zero--unless $f$ has some regularity such as being continuous, and then this set of measure zero is in fact empty.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $f$ and integrate by parts to get $\int_V \|\nabla f\|^2 dx = -\int_V f^4 dx$.  Since $\|\nabla f\|$ and $f^4$ are both non-negative, this implies that $f=0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides by $f$ and integrate by parts to get

$\int_V \|\nabla f\|^2 dx = -\int_V f^4 dx$.

Since $\|\nabla f\|$ and $f^4$ are both non-negative, this implies that $f=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: Or, both of those could be negative.

Comment: $\lVert \nabla f\rVert$ tends to be non-negative rather than negative, Dhaivat.

Answer (score 0):

Let me extend the boundary beyond its original limit, filling up the newly added space by f=0.

$\int\int\int \nabla^2 f dV=\int\int\int \nabla.(\nabla f) dV$

$=\int\int (\nabla f).n dS=0$

Therefore,
$\int\int\int \nabla^2 f dV=0$

But $\int\int\int \nabla^2 f dV$ for the additional space is zero. Therefore the integral is zero for the original space also.

We may now consider a sub-volume[V'] inside the original 3D region. Let the surface/boundary of this sub-volume be S'. We may try to perform the same trick as before  but the difficulty is that  f in general is not zero on the boundary.A continuous extension with f=0 will not be possible. This time we may carry out an *infinitesimally small* extension so the gradf becomes zero on the extended boundary. Again the volume integral is zero.

The integral seems to vanish for an arbitrary volume